# Formatting and use a condition to derive % and N/A

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2015

MyData
0.00
0.25
0.80
0.00
0.00
0.77

In the SSRS report I need to display output as below

MyData
N/A
25%
80%
N/A
N/A
77%

I have tried below code in the Visual Studio Expression

=iif(fields!mydata = "0" then "N/A" fields!mydata & "%")

It is not working.

Can you help

=iif(fields!mydata = "0" then "N/A" fields!mydata & "%")

Output on the report should look like below
MyData
N/A
25%
80%
N/A
N/A
77%

Answer (score 1):

The SSR IIF function doesn't use the THEN keyword (nor ELSE) - it uses commas to separate the function parameters using the syntax:

```
=IIF(<Boolean Expression>, <TRUE Result>, <False Result>)
```

There's also a FORMATPERCENT function to do inline formatting with text in a text box. It has a second parameter for the number of places to show after the decimal.

> Returns an expression formatted as a percentage (that is, multiplied
>   by 100) with a trailing % character.

-Visual Studio 2016 Function Description

Your expression would be

```
=IIF(Fields!mydata.Value = "0", "N/A", FORMATPERCENT(Fields!mydata.Value, 0) )
```

[image]

Comment: @Ramkee - Yes - the FORMATPERCENT function adds the % sign.

Comment: it is working but when I have a value 0.5045 it is showing as 550% rather than 50.45%

Comment: @Ramkee - I checked out the value and it seems to be working correctly when I use a parameter for the source. `=IIF(Parameters!Number.Value = "0", "N/A", FORMATPERCENT(Parameters!Number.Value, 2) )` Are you sure about the value? I usually add an extra column with the actual field value when trying to troubleshoot issues like this.

Comment: Yes values are correct. Not sure where it is going wrong.

Comment: it is not a numeric, it is a data field. May be there I am getting the issue

Comment: @Ramkee - You can try converting the number to a decimal with the CDEC function to see if that helps, but it should be doing it automatically already. `FORMATPERCENT(CDEC(Fields!mydata.Value), 0)`

Comment: Ok will try this tomorrow and will let you know